# React-table rerender table when deleting a row

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, react-table-v7

I'm using react-table in my project and I have a button to delete the row. It works fine but when the row is deleted the table is rerendered ( loses current page in pagination, the search filters, etc.) Is there a way to prevent this to happen?

My code:

```
const Taxis = ({data}) => {

     const [taxis, setTaxis] = useState([...data])


     const columns = useMemo(() => [
     {
          Header: 'Active',
          accessor: 'active',
          Cell: ({ value }) => {
               return <p className="flex justify-end md:block"><Icon path={value ? mdiCheck : mdiClose} size={1} className={`md:mx-auto ${value ? 'text-green-400' : 'text-red-400'}`}/></p>  
          }
     },
     {
          Header: 'Acciones',
          accessor: 'actions',
          Cell: ({row}) => {
               return <><div className="flex justify-end md:justify-center pb-2 md:pb-0">
                    <div className="group relative">
                         <button className="flex rounded-md p-1 text-primary border border-primary hover:border-secondary hover:text-secondary mr-2">
                              <Icon path={mdiPencil} size={1} />
                         </button>
                         <span className="absolute hover-sibling:opacity-100 z-30 w-20 right-2 opacity-0 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg text-primary px-2 py-1 mt-1 border border-gray-200 text-center text-sm">
                              Editar taxi
                         </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="relative">
                         <button className="flex text-blanco border border-primary hover:border-secondary rounded-md p-1 bg-primary hover:bg-secondary" 
                           onClick={() => {/*this is my function to delete*/
                             const data = await fetch(`${APP_CONSTANTS.REST_API}`,{
                                method: "DELETE"
                             })
                             if (data.ok) {
                               setTaxis(taxis.filter( taxi => taxi.idtaxi !== row.original.idtaxi))
                             }
                           }}>
                              <Icon path={mdiDeleteForever} size={1} />
                         </button>
                         <span className="absolute hover-sibling:opacity-100 z-30 w-24 right-0 opacity-0 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg text-primary px-2 py-1 mt-1 border border-gray-200 text-center text-sm">
                              Eliminar taxi
                         </span>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </>
          }
     },

   ], [taxis])
   
   return (
        <>
          <Table columns={columns} data={taxis} table={'Taxis'} />
        </>
   ) 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The docs have the answer!](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/faq#how-do-i-stop-my-table-state-from-automatically-resetting-when-my-data-changes) Namely, you have to manually prevent those things from updating, by using the `autoResetX` properties on the table. In this case, you'd probably want `autoResetPage` and `autoResetFilters` set to `false` in order to prevent those fields from updating when your dataset does.